# How to change android:windowSoftInputMode value base on presented screen in react native

Tags: react-native

I understand that we can set value for android:windowSoftInputMode in AndroidMainifest.xml file

But what if I want to change it programmatically based on the screen/component is presented

Let say when component A/screen A is presented. set android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustResize

when component B/screen B is presented. set android:windowSoftInputMode = stateAlwaysHidden

Is this possible in react native?